# PHP convert date to DD-M-YY

Tags: php, date

I'm trying to validate a date like 17-JAN-1985 in my code.

Here is the function I'm using:

```
function fncDate($date){
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('DD-M-YY', $date);
    $result = $d && $d->format('DD-M-YY') == $date;
    if(!$result){
        return "Date should be in the following format: DD-MMM-YYYY"; 
    }
}
```

This returns always false: `fncDate("17-JAN-1985");`

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your format string for reading (parsing) the date should be `'d-M-Y'`, not 'DD-M-YY'. And when you compare, you need to uppercase both sides since PHP will generate "Jan" instead of "JAN". Furthermore you forgot to return the value at all.

Here is fully working code:

```
function fncDate($date){
   $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-Y', $date);
   $result = $d && strtoupper($d->format('d-M-Y')) == strtoupper($date);
   if(!$result){
       return "Date should be in the following format: DD-MMM-YYYY";.
   }
   return $result;
}
```

Comment: I tested it and it is not working with the format "d-M-Y"

Comment: I've updated my answer. It is possible that you need to use different format for parsing, and different format for generating the date again, I'm not sure about that though since i'm not using these strange constructs. Furthermore, your generated date may have "Jan" instead of "JAN" thus you may need to uppercase all to match it.

Comment: Yes you are right Thanks I noticed it too

Comment: Updated the answer again, provided correct function for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function fncDate($date)
{
    $date = date_create($date);

    $date1= date_format($date, 'Y-m-d ');

    $result = $date1 && $date1 == $date;

    if(!$result)
    {
       echo "Date should be in the following format: DD-MMM-YYYY"; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Ok";
    }
}
```